# How to split/slice a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I saw this code in w3resource:

```
C = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n']
def list_slice(S, step):
    return [S[i::step] for i in range(step)]
print(list_slice(C,3))
```

Output :`[['a', 'd', 'g', 'j', 'm'], ['b', 'e', 'h', 'k', 'n'], ['c', 'f', 'i', 'l']]`

I tried it without list comprehension and a function:

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n']
step = int(input("Step of every element: "))
for i in range(step):
    print(letters[i::step])
```

Output:

```
['a', 'd', 'g', 'j', 'm']
['b', 'e', 'h', 'k', 'n']
['c', 'f', 'i', 'l']
```

is it possible to make my output like this `[['a', 'd', 'g', 'j', 'm'], ['b', 'e', 'h', 'k', 'n'], ['c', 'f', 'i', 'l']]` without using list comprehension and without making another variable with an empty list?

Comment: No, its not possible. you have to store the value in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

not a list comprehension solution, but since you want an element having certain distance/step in the list to be in the same list, then you can see that those element index share single property altogether which have the same remainder to the step value, using this approach you can save those value for that index remainder in a key-value pair of dict and in result you can take the values which are nonempty.

```
C = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n']

def func(lis, slic):
    res = {i:[] for i in range(len(lis)//slic)}
    for i in range(len(lis)):
        res[i%slic].append(lis[i])
    return [i for i in  res.values() if i!=[]]

print(func(C, 3))

# Output :[['a', 'd', 'g', 'j', 'm'], ['b', 'e', 'h', 'k', 'n'], ['c', 'f', 'i', 'l']]
```

Comment: this is the first time i saw the `//` in range. is it a division or not?

Comment: yes it is absolute division. it is divding the list into `len(list)//step`reminder and in those one it is adding the values